# How many valuation are there for a set of atoms?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm studying propositional logic. On my notebook I wrote:

Theorem: If v is a function from ATOMS (set of atoms) into $\{0,1\}$ then exists a unique valuation $[[*]]_v$ such that $[[\psi]]_v=v(\psi)$ for any $\psi \in$ ATOMS.

I agree completely. Then:

From the theorem, it follows that there are $2^{\aleph_0}$, where $\aleph_0$ (aleph zero) is the cardinality of the set of natural numbers.

Can someone explain the last sentence?

Comment: There are countable many (i.e. $\aleph_0$) propositional letters (*atoms*); every *valuation* is a function from the set of atoms to $2$. Tus, the set of all functions has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: See [Representing subsets as functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Representing_subsets_as_functions).

Comment: Thank you @MauroALLEGRANZA I needed two months to understand (I hope) your comment. If you write the answer below I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: Just one thing: we use $\aleph$ to tell that there are infinity propositional atoms, but instead of using the $\infty$ we use $\aleph_0$ which is a more precise notation?

Comment: There are many [alephs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number) : $\aleph_0, \aleph_1, \ldots$; usually, the language of prop calculus has countable many prop symbols, i.e. $\aleph_0$.